# Вопрос по синтаксису

Tags: php, синтаксис

Пытаюсь получить страницу с которой пришёл юзер вот таким образом, а потом на неё сделать редирект через несколько секунд. Но вот проблема, если я пишу вот так: URL=$H то он редиректит на WWW.***.ru/$H. Понимаю что ошибка где-то в синтаксисе, но я пока новичок в пхп. Скажите как вернее написать.

```
$H=getenv("HTTP_REFERER");
echo $H;
header('Refresh: 5; URL=$H'); //redirect с задержкой
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header( "Refresh: 5; URL=$H" )
```

Comment: Добавлю, что переменная в одинарных ковычках не подставляется. С одинарными ковычками можно было бы сделать так: header('Refresh: 5; URL=' . $H);

Comment: и я еще поумничаю =) это называется интерполяция строки http://www.webmasterwiki.ru/PHP/Interpoljacija